# How to generate infinitely many solutions to $x^2-dy^2 = 4$?

Tags: number-theory, pell-type-equations

I was looking at how to generate infinitely many solutions to the Pell's equation $x^2-dy^2 = 1$, where $d$ is a square-free positive integer. On [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#Generalized_Pell's_equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#Generalized_Pell%27s_equation) it is also said that $x^2-dy^2 = 4$ can have infinitely many solutions if one solution is found.

How would I generate infinitely many solutions for $x^2-dy^2 = 4$?

Comment: Note that $$x^2-dy^2=4 \Rightarrow \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2}-d\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)^{2}=1$$

Comment: I think you mean *infinitely many* solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a^2 - db^2 = \alpha$ and $u^2 - dv^2 = \beta$, then $(au + dbv)^2 - d(av + bu)^2 = \alpha\beta$.

This gives you infinitely many solutions to $x^2 - dy^2 = 4$, once you have one solution to $x^2 - dy^2 = 4$ and one solution to $x^2 - dy^2 = 1$ (the latter always exists).